# Convert a character column with multiple date formats to a date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

I'm trying to update a date column with from a varchar column

```
update tbl set columnA = columnB
```

Here, `columnA` is a varchar data type and `columnB` is a date data type. `columnA` has various types of date formats, for instance, 09302012, 9/30/2012, 2012-09-30 and more different types

How can I write a single query to update the column with the various types of date formats in single query.

EDITED:::

sorry about the mess up.. i just Realized that these are individual(pieces) updates in ssis package...

we have diff types(6) of makes and for each make they send different files with different date formats

for type 1 contains date format like 09/22/2011 9/22/2011 and 2012-09-22

and the rest all types follows same format..its 09222012

so now i need to write query for individual types...(straightly speaking only two logics one for type 1 and the other for rest all types)

the first query logic contains a case statement for three formats and the second query logic contain logic for other format...

the end result should show up like 2012-09-22 00:00:00 (ie yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss)
can u help me out

am a T-sql guy and dont know any thng aby pl-sql(if its in t-sql i would directly do i with convert and substring)

Comment: Your `varchar2` column should be in a specific format as per your `to_date` format mask. If you do not know what format is in `varchar2` column it could be an endless `if...else` to determine the format for every row in the `varchar2` column. That is the reason why `varchar2` type for date data is a bad idea.

Comment: According to your `UPDATE` statement, you are trying to assign the `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` column.  According to the text and title of your question, you are trying to assign a `VARCHAR2` to a `DATE` column.  Is your `UPDATE` statement reversed (i.e. you are really assigning `columnA`, the `VARCHAR2`, to `columnB`, the `DATE`)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

Firstly you do it properly next time and store dates in a DATE data type; if this is supplied data then you yell<sup>1</sup> at your suppliers.

The simplest way to clean your data would be to create a function that tests if a date is in a certain format:

```
create or replace function is_date ( 
      P_String in varchar2
    , P_Date_Format in varchar2
      ) return number is

   l_date date;

begin

   l_date := to_date(P_String, P_Date_Format);

   return 1;
exception when others then
   return 0;
end;
```

Next you pick a [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) and update just that one.

```
update my_table
   set date_column = to_date(char_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
 where is_date(char_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = 1
```

You then have to pick a different format model and do it all over again until you don't have any records in your date column that are NULL.

<sub>1. Yelling may be a bit much, but make sure you're heard.</sub>

---

This could be distilled into a single query with a large CASE statement:

```
update my_table
   set date_column = case when is_date(char_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = 1
                               then to_date(char_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                          when is_date(char_column, 'yyyymmdd') = 1
                               then to_date(char_column, 'yyyymmdd')
                          ...
                          snip
                          ...
                     end
```

Comment: Yeah I use to yell at the suppliers all the time :)

Comment: sorry about the mess up.. i just Realized that these are individual(pieces) updates in ssis package...

we have diff types(6) of makes and for each make they send different files with different date formats

for type 1 contains date format like 09/22/2011 9/22/2011 and 2012-09-22 

and the rest all types follows same format..its 09222012

Comment: so now i need to write query for individual types...(straightly speaking only two logics one for type 1 and the other for rest all types)

the first query logic contains a case statement for three formats and the second query logic contain logic for other format...

the end result should show up like 2012-09-22 00:00:00 (ie yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss)
can u help me out

am a T-sql guy and dont know any thng aby pl-sql(if its in t-sql i would directly do i with convert and substring)

Comment: @MtKr, you can still use my answer, just use `to_date()` as explained.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a problem like this then my first question would be how to programatically detect what date format columnA is for each row.
Assuming that it's doable within a reasoanble LOE (I don't know the complete spectrum of your date formats) I'd then see how I could use the CASE expression to detect the format and then format the date accordingly for each case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I think you should be able to update your table in one statement.  It's not the most elegant solution, but the following should work.

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET columnA = DECODE(type, '1', DECODE(INSTR(columnB, '-'), 5, TO_DATE(columnB, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                                                  TO_DATE(columnB, 'MM/DD/YYYY')),
                                   TO_DATE(columnB, 'MMDDYYYY'));
```

In the above statement I'm assuming you have a column named **type** that indicates which date format column B is in.  The above statement uses the DECODE to determine if the type is 1.  Since the type 1 has 3 possible formats , the statement will then try to determine which format columnB is in.  To make our job easier we only need to test for the YYYY-MM-DD format as we can use the MM/DD/YYYY format with both 09/22/2011 and 9/22/2011.  So we use the INSTR function to determine the location of the first '-' character. If that position is 5, then we know the column is in the **YYYY-MM-DD** format and can use the appropriate date mask.  If the position is not 5, then we know columnB is in the **MM/DD/YYYY** format.  Lastly, if the type isn't 1, then we know the date mask should be **MMDDYYYY**.